# Woocommerce not running with any php version

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

wocommerce plugin is not installing and produces this error:

```
Error: Current PHP version does not meet minimum requirements for WooCommerce.
```

I was using PHP 7.0 on cpanel hosting, and I tried 7.1 to 7.4 (latest), but woocommerce is producing the same error on every version. How to get this fixed? Thanks

Comment: What version of woocommerce are you installing, and which version does it show for both `php -i` on the command line and in `phpinfo()` in your browser?

Comment: @aynber the theme shopkeeper includes woocommerce 3.9.1 and I have now changed php version to most latest 7.4 but still it gives error

Comment: Make sure the php version in both the browser and command line match.

Comment: @aynber how to check command line php version. I am operating from Windows, and website is residing on namecheap hosting with cpanel

Comment: You'd need to log into your host via ssh, and do `php -i`. You can also double-check that the PHP version in cPanel is correct by creating a page that just has `<?php phpinfo();` and going to that page.

Comment: @aynber I tried phpinfo(), it shows php version 5.6.0... I wonder why it is not updated. I have selected the latest php version 7.4 from cpanel php version selection options.

Comment: You'll need to contact your host to find out why it's not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hosts implement php management seperate from a global cPanel php version. But also a global php level set in cPanel may not overwrite an individual folder setting if it was modified. 
You may want to check the PHP version manager in cPanel on different levels of the folder structure in wordpress at it is possible for a single folder to have a different php than the rest of your account.

So for example 'wp-content' or 'plugins' may have a different version or maybe the entire installation directory.

Comment: I have changed the directory of site php version through cpanel, it worked